# Is there a replacement component for dcmemo (Dream Company) for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, components

I've used a component called dcmemo which is part of a component pack from Dream Company which went out of business a few years ago.  Now that I'm upgrading to the latest Delphi I can't install this component dispite having the source and making tons of fixes to it.

After looking around on the web everyone pretty much says it's extremely difficult to upgrade the dream company components to work with the latest delphi which leaves me looking for a replacement which can do almost the same stuff.

I'm sure someone has had this exact same problem before.  What can I replace dcmemo with?

Comment: There are a number of potential replacements, it very much depends on what functionality of dcmemo you specifically used. So instead of asking "what can I replace dcmemo with" you might be better of to describe your requirements and ask what component will fulfill them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Try SynEdit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/synedit/). It's free and has been under development for a long time. I'd advise you use the  latest sources which includes a code folding and tested and working code/dpks for most every version of delphi.

If you have svn installed, use the command below to get all the files.

svn co https://synedit.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/synedit synedit

Comment: SynEdit seems to do what I need so far.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I've used TPlusMemo for many years and have found it well worth the price.  It has been recently upgraded for XE.  http://www.ecmqc.com/plusmemo/pmHome.htm

Good luck!